# cd to a directory when its path is entered as a command (instead of "foo is a directory" error)

Tags: bash, shell, directory

I hate when `bash` gives me "duh!" kind of error:

```
foo$ ./bar
-bash: ./bar: is a directory
```

I used to love AmigaOS shell in which "execution" of a directory simply meant setting it as the current directory:

```
foo$ ./bar
bar$
```

Is it possible in `bash`? (without infinite number of aliases of course.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash 4.0 has the `autocd` option.

From the [Official FAQ](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/FAQ):

> There is a new 'autocd' option that,
>   when enabled, causes bash to attempt
>   to `cd' to a directory name that is
>   supplied as the first word of a simple
>   command.

Also, take a look at the `CDPATH` environment variable in `man bash` for any version since at least as early as 2.0. It allows you to shorten `cd` commands by searching the listed directories for the directory specified in a `cd` command.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about bash but this is possible in zsh.

```
# ~/.zshrc
setopt autocd
```

---

**Edit**: you could probably handle this in bash the same way ubuntu catches command not found

```
    # bashrc

    function command_not_found_handle {
            if [ -d $1]; then
                cd $1
            else
                echo command not found
            fi
    }
```

Comment: command_not_found_handle doesn't seem to do anything for me [GNU bash, version 3.2.17(1)-release (i386-apple-darwin9.0)] (tried .bashrc and .profile)

Comment: I had quick google on this after i posted it, but i'm not sure how debian/ubuntu actually make that function work, unless they've modified bash to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As documentation for future searches, this is also possible in csh / tcsh, though the name differs:

```
# ~/.cshrc
set implicitcd
```

This value may also be set to verbose, which then echoes the cd commands that are invoked in this manner.